# Need active tab URL in IE8/IE9 using WIN32 API

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Current URL in IE Using Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158341/get-current-url-in-ie-using-visual-basic)

I need to get the active tab url of the user's browser in IE8/IE9 using WIN 32 API.
I need the URL which is accessed by the user in the browser which is currently accessed. I have to use the URl value in Windows service.

User can open any number of tabs as per his requirement. But at a time only one tab of the browser is active. I need the the URL of the tab which is active.
I have tried to get the active tab URL using ShellWindowsClass. But we get all the URL of the browser. Also i need to get the URL in windows service. So kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Do you have any idea where to start? (What's your question?)

Comment: there is a similar question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158341/get-current-url-in-ie-using-visual-basic

Answer (score 1):

Try these :

Internet Explorer URL Crawler .. dont know if it works on latest browsers.

http://stoyanov.in/code/ie-url-crawler/

and one more similar link..

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/46881/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-internet-explorer.aspx