# Problems importing HTML from defined string

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I have a piece of code that loads a website and clicks a link that opens a popup. The contents of this popup is what I need to be imported into Excel (VBA) so I can manipulate that data. The issue is that this link's web address always changes, but the link is always in the same place.

The following code defines the currently active IE instance's URL as "IEURL". I would like to use the code to import the table but I get an error "Run-time error '1004': The address of this site is not valid. Check the address and try again".

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim IEURL As String
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
'apiShowWindow objIE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
objIE.navigate "http://www.youtube.com"
objIE.Visible = True
Do While objIE.READYSTATE <> 4 And objIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

'Call Sleep
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

IEURL = objIE.LocationURL


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Rows("6:250").Delete
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;IEURL", _
Destination:=Range("a6"))

.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me out here? 
P.S. I just used YouTube as an example here, as it demonstrates the same problem as the actual website I am trying to import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objIE.LocationURL` property returns a string which you are storing in a string variable. When you later try to use that variable you should append it to a string rather than just putting the name of the variable inside the string. So change

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;IEURL", _
```

to

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & IEURL, _
```

btw, in Excel 2013, your sample code fails at `IEURL = objIE.LocationURL`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm actually using Excel 2010 which does not return an error on that line. (I got that piece of code from the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158341/get-current-url-in-ie-using-visual-basic 

Making these changes in my code no longer produces the error, but it does not import anything when it runs. Any ideas on this? Perhaps this is not the right approach to importing the page?

Comment: I think that might be a separate question and probably depends on how the website constructs the pages.

Comment: Use of this code in a new spreadsheet worked fine. Thanks for helping!